# When were "2nd stage pushers" first used?

Tags: spaceflight-firsts, stage-separation

The question [Falcon 9 2nd stage pusher; how far does it continue to extend as it accelerates separation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33754/12102) includes (and further explains) the GIF below.

**Question:** What was the first use of a "2nd stage pusher", a rod that extends from one stage and pushes against the other in order to add a small relative separation velocity between the two before the upper stage starts its engine?

[image: Falcon 9 2nd stage separation pusher]

Comment: companion question: [Are “2nd stage pushers” limited to the Falcon-9, fairly standard, or somewhere in-between?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40503/12102)